# tikz: arrow with two heads, why?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

why do i get two heads with this code? how can i get rid of that one at the end?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    important line/.style={thick,shorten <=4pt,->}
  ]


  \draw[important line] (8.5,1.5) coordinate (A)  edge node[above,sloped] {\tiny text}  (7,2.7)
        coordinate (B) node[] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: two heads]

Comment: Short answer: Replace `\draw` by `\path`.